# Unable to find RubyGems in site_ruby or core Ruby？

Tags: ruby, jekyll, devkit

I want to install ruby on my windows,

```
  ruby dk.rb init
```

then modify config.yml, and install:

```
E:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install
```

but the output is error:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find RubyGems in site_ruby or core Ruby. Please
install RubyGems and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'.
```

Did I lose something?

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved it, was to open up my config.yml, and put in

```
- C:/path_to_ruby
```

That's it. Just the root directory. Note that the slashes are /, and not backslashes, just incase you copy paste from address bar.

Answer (score 2):

This same issue happened to my ruby installation obtained from compiled source on a Windows 8.1 box.

In my case 'ruby dk.rb init' was not able to populate the existing ruby installation, so I manually entered it into the config.yml file.

So, instead of adding the rubydir absolute path (i.e. C:/ruby215), I had to enter the following:

> -- << absolute-path-to-ruby-install >>/usr

For example: - C:/ruby215/usr

Afterward the command 'ruby dk.rb install' ran successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but could not resolve it for a day even after going through every answer here. In the end I realized that you need to remove the comments not just for the "C:/path_to_ruby" but also for the three "---" at the beginning, for this to work.

Comment: made my day, I am not one how reinstalls rais from scratch twice a day

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the instructions in this site http://rubyinstaller.org/ it really helped me when i try to do that.

Here is another site to help you out https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Comment: Thanks, but I did it in another way.

Comment: can you share how you did it so that other people with the same problem can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and here is what I had to do for what its worth.

1. First of all I was not running command prompt as admin
2. Next I had to add my Ruby main folder path to config.yml

After I did both of these things, it installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is I did include the path to Ruby in my config.yml, the error still exists. It turned out somehow I had two paths:

```
- e:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2
- C:/Ruby22-x64
```

After deleting the first path, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had 7 different paths in my **config.yml** file for 3 different Rubys. This because I wanted clean rubies for different projects.

I was using Windows, so used the rubyinstaller to create ruby directories. I had one "ruby" directory from a gz that was not proper (but followed the convention I was using) and should have been deleted. When I ran **dk** it choked on that directory, didn't mention it specifically in the error messages but it was next in line. Deleted the directory and the listing in the **config.yml** file and life became sweet again.

Answer (score 0):

DevKit installation gives error. If you are using Ruby for 64bit, uninstall the the Ruby and DevKit. Installing 32bit version of Ruby and DevKit solved my problem.